# Is there a way to use a variable by combining two other variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables

My problem is best explained in code form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
var x = "x";
var y = 1;
var x1 = "something";
alert(x+y);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would then want it to alert the value of x1, which in this case would be "something".
As you can see this obviously doesn't work but how would you do this in JavaScript? It would be much apreciated if you could keep you answer as simple as possible, as I'm new to programming.

EDIT:

I just want to clarify here that the above code isn't actually my project. I was just trying to explain my problem in a simple way so everyone would understand me. I'll put an example of my actual project code below.

```
value_+x=document.getElementById('square_+x');
```

Again I know this wont work but would you change this to

```
value_4=document.getElementById('square_4');
```

If x happend to be 4?

Comment: You have a serious misconception here: What you are manipulating by writing `x+y` is the *value* of the variables and **not** their names.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a global `window` variable, you can do

```
window[x+y];
```

Comment: Ick. Globals. Best avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when do you know if it's a global window variable?

Comment: Have you declared it as one? Is your variable declaration in the global namespace?

Comment: I guess it isn't then. I will try eval(x+y) in my project. By the way why are people saying that eval is a bad idea?

Comment: By the way your code looks, it is in the global namespace. If the `var` is not within a `function` or a property of another object, then it is global. As for eval, that's been discussed at length http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough when asking my question so I've clarified it above.

Comment: Same principle applies - see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gfax6/

Answer (score 0):

this ll help you provided the documentation as well
alert([eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)(x+y))